# Need to click twice to trigger .one() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed to geta toggle function in my code, so I searched for it and got this. Now I implemented it into my code (below code is simplified), but you have to click the button twice to make it work properly. After clicking twice it works normally.

What causes this problem and how can I fix this?

```js
var triggerbtn = $('#trigger');

function showThis() {
  triggerbtn.text('Show this!');
  $(this).one("click", hideThis);
}

function hideThis() {
  triggerbtn.text('Hide this!');
  $(this).one("click", showThis);
}

triggerbtn.one("click", showThis);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Show this!</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default state of button is `show` and on first click you are again trying to `show` it. It should have been `hide` for first click

```js
var triggerbtn = $('#trigger');

function showThis() {
  triggerbtn.text('Show this!');
  $(this).one("click", hideThis);
}

function hideThis() {
  triggerbtn.text('Hide this!');
  $(this).one("click", showThis);
}

triggerbtn.one("click", hideThis);  // Here is the change
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Show this!</button>
```

Comment: Uhm, that I didn't notice that... Thanks.